# Sails v0.11.0-rc10 assets loading timeout

Tags: timeout, sails.js, assets, beta

After upgrade to v0.11.0-rc10, sometimes, random assets (both css and js) loading takes a long time.
Does anyone has same problem?

[Firebug screen](http://s11.postimg.org/e8g2t45z7/image.png)

[Chrome dev screen](http://s14.postimg.org/az3yhu9bl/image.png)

P.S. All grunt tasks has completed successful

P.S.S. sorry for my english

Comment: I think this might be worth filing as an issue: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is here (by @swarthy): https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2616#issuecomment-74642658

> updating node from v0.10 to v0.12 solved the problem.